# PDF cropping incorrectly is some documents but not others using pypdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf

I have two pdf forms. Both forms are nearly identical. On the first form I extract a field at 610 < y < 628. On the first PDF form, it worked great. But on another PDF form, it failed and extracted coordinates at y ~ 332. I thought maybe the crop box was misaligned (the coordinates are for the crop box, right?) so I set the crop box to the media box coordinates, reset the origin, and printed the dimensions (to make sure it wasn't rotated).

```py
def reset_origin(input_pdf: Path):
    pdf_file = open(input_pdf, 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    
    for page_num, p in enumerate(pdf_reader.pages):
        page_obj = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
        page_obj.cropbox.upper_right = (page_obj.mediabox.upper_right)
        page_obj.cropbox.lower_left = (page_obj.mediabox.lower_left)
        page_obj.cropbox.lower_left = (0, 0)
        print(f"upper_right media box is {page_obj.mediabox.upper_right} ")
        print(f"upper_right crop box is {page_obj.cropbox.upper_right}")
        pdf_writer.add_page(page_obj)
    
    pdf_file.close()
    pdf_output_file = open(input_pdf, 'wb')
    pdf_writer.write(pdf_output_file)
    pdf_output_file.close()
```

```
upper_right media box is (612, 792)
upper_right crop box is (612, 792)
```

These are the same for both the good and bad PDFs.

After extracting the entire page with `0 < y < 792`  I capture text within the following box:

```
upper_right = (610, 792)
lower_left = (0, 200)
```

It text with y < 200 is missing.

I extract my field as follows :

```py
 def visitor(text, cm, tm, font_dict, font_size):
        '''
        text = input text
        cm = transformation matrix
        tm = text matrix
        font_dict : unused
        font_size: unused
        '''
        length = 792
        x = tm[4]
        y=tm[5]
        if 0 < y < length
            parts.append(text)
    parts = []
    page = reader.pages[0]
    my_text=page.extract_text(visitor_text=visitor)
    my_text = "".join(parts)
    print(f"my text:  {my_text}")
```

However, if set the condition to `0 < y < length + 1000` I get the entire page, including the missing text y LESS THAN 200!

I don't understand, is the page rotated so the origin is in the upper right? But why does the text extend beyond y = 792 if the media box is 610 x 792?

The good PDF is v1.3 written by Ghostscript 8.51 and the bad pdfs are v1.7 written by Microsoft PDF print. Of course, after transformation they all say they were written by pypdf.

Any tips how I can correct the coordinate system in this pdf? Maybe reset the rotation?

Comment: the documents are here. I sanitized them (hope it doesn't break anything).
https://transfer.sh/O5PGwV/bad.pdf
https://transfer.sh/EFYs9E/good.pdf

Comment: Just a note: the first batch of files, all six went through. But another agency submitted three files, all three failed from that user.

Comment: There are no fields just text placed on top of the form (I deleted the text to sanitize it). The rotation in the bad form is because my file was opening it, resetting the origin, and at one point rotating because I thought the origin may have been mislocated. Then I save the form in the pypdf. So the good form is original and the bad form was oversaved by pypdf and I don't have an original.

Answer (score 1):

@KJ said he found a stray annotation that was way out of range. I deleted all the extraneous data, just leaving the data I needed to extract. By deleting the other text in form, including what I believe what may have been the out-of-range annotations, the extraction worked. Somehow some text I deleted was changing the grid system, and when the text was deleted, the grid went back to normal.

Comment: Huh, interesting. That could be a robustness-issue of pypdf (a broken PDF, but pypdf might be able to deal with it better) or even a bug (PDF is fine, just a special case that pypdf hasn't considered).

Comment: The business client says the forms are generated from an...Excel spreadsheet. It is possible they modified a cell way out of range. Excel is very fragile. Business is going to get everyone onboard using the correct Excel template (if they must).